# Is there a better alternative to mail merge for sending out emails containing Excel tables?

Tags: email, microsoft-excel

I need to send weekly scorecards containing data that is stored in excel tables. The tables are currently created in word with a .csv file as the source. It is a lengthy process to combine the data into one row to work with a mail merge and often my computer can't handle the memory it takes. I'm working with close to 300 columns in the final output. I have yet to find an alternative to word mail merges in my research. Programs I have available are Excel, Alteryx, and Power BI. I don't know of this capability in either program yet. If anyone can point me to some resources for alternatives to mail merges for sending out emails with tables, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the templates different somehow?  I ask because you're supposed to be able to create a single template in word, and combine it with any data set that has matching column names.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office including but not limited to Excel have macro language.
This is VBA, and it very similar to VBS or Visual Basic Scripting language.

You might be able record the steps your doing as a macro, but writing a program in VBA would like allow you to do it all automatically.

You can keep customizing your script until is 100% right.

You mention combining rows?  concat(a1,b1,c1,d1,...) or concat(a1,a2,a3...)
=CONCAT(A1:A5)